# Selenium webdriver attribute error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm just getting started using selenium, but the following code results in 'AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome''

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = 'C://Users/name/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

url = 'http://www.google.com'
browser.get(url)
```

I've been unable to pin down the cause of this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try installing Chrome Webdriver for your plaform. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: It's already installed it in the path written in the third line of the above code

Comment: How did you install selenium? Please add the following output to you `python -V`, `pip freeze` and `dir /a/p` in your current directory where the code is running

Answer (score 0):

Use single slash instead of double in path like this :

```
driver_path = 'C:Users/name/chromedriver'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are storing the absolute path of the `chromedriver.exe` in a variable you need to include the `.exe` part as well.

Additionally, as you are using `'` i.e. single quotes you need to use `\` i.e. the forward slashes along with the `r (raw)` switch.

Finally, when you pass the `variable` while creating the `webdriver` instance, you need to mention the argument `executable_path`.

Here is your own code with some simple modifications:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r'C:\Users\name\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
url = 'http://www.google.com'
browser.get(url)
```